# Stretching color column above the container to the bottom of the screen bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay-theme

I need to pass the `background` of the column above the container until the end of the screen. As I can do with bootstrap and is responsive? I am now doing with a `width` but my scroll appears.

I attached a photo

[image]

```
<div class="portlet-layout row-fluid">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="row-fluid portlet-column" id="column-2">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-3 no-float">
                <div class="portlet-column portlet-column" id="columnaColor-3">
                    $processor.processColumn("columnaColor-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content")
                </div>
                 <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-4">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>

#columnaColor-3{
    background: #2e373c;
}
```

Comment: http://www.image-share.com/upload/3032/255m.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.col-*` and the `.container` makes :

    `padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;`

I just added a rule to the `column` you want to remove this with:

     `margin-right:-30px`

ps: I changed the `sm` to `xs` so you could see more clearly the changes in small screens.

### UPDATE

if in case you are placing a log long (continuous) texts; you can break the text with:

```
div{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```css
#columnaColor-3{
    background: #2e373c;
    color:red;    margin-right:-30px
}
div{
    word-break: break-all;
}
.container{
    background: green;
}
#column-4{
    background: blue;
    margin-right:-30px

}
#column-2{
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="portlet-layout row-fluid">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="row-fluid portlet-column" id="column-2">
                                        $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")

                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3 no-float">
                <div class="portlet-column portlet-column" id="columnaColor-3">
                    $processor.processColumn("columnaColor-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content")
                </div>
                 <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-4">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help Joao! The problem is that I need to get to the end of the container with color col-xs-3 1200px desktop screens. If I put margin-right to the end of the container, I get scrool horizontal, so it would not be responsive ... I hope you can help me :( @AlvaroJoao

Comment: @Naviego can you post the actual text you  are rendering ? My guess is that you adding long string, if the problem is that  I know what to do....